# Please indicate how to use the EventListener class in .Net 4.6

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, c#-5.0

I have tried to use the System.Diagnostics.Trace.EventListener in a Windows Store App but it is an abstract class.  There does not seem to be any classes that descend from it to call a constructor upon.  How is this class used.  Please be aware I am not talking about an event handler.  every other log post on this site where someone has asked about an EventListener they have been answered with information about an Event Handler.  Please answer the question that is actually asked.

Answer (score 3):

`EventListener` is not intended to be used directly, but rather subclasses *by you*.

Its rarely needed, as the goal of the ETW APIs is typically just to publish events, which works via `EventSource`.  You only need to create an `EventListener` if you want to reroute the events to a different source.

For details including a full sample code of how to accomplish this, see the [Logging Sample for Windows Store Apps](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7) on the MSDN Samples.